# speed up mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.  One is a click-log, that records the exact time we received a click.  The 2nd is a dollars / day table that records the amount we earned each day with a particular site.

I need to calculate the daily CPC for each site.  The query bellow is working, but takes almost a minute.

Here's the result of explain:

```
id  select_type     table           type    possible_keys       key     key_len     ref     rows       Extra
1   SIMPLE          click_log       ALL     url_id,click_time   NULL    NULL        NULL    1404209    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          daily_dollars   ref     url_id,date         date    3           func    6          Using where
```

And the query:

```
SELECT date( click_log.click_time ) AS DAY,
       click_log.shorturl AS site,
       daily_dollars.money AS earned,
       count( click_log.click_id ) AS clicks,
       daily_dollars.money / count( click_log.click_id ) AS CPC
FROM `yourls_log` AS click_log, yourls_url_money AS daily_dollars
WHERE click_log.click_time >= "2011-07-01"
    AND click_log.url_id = daily_dollars.url_id
    AND date( click_log.click_time ) = daily_dollars.date
GROUP BY DAY , click_log.shorturl
```

Anything I can do to speed this up?

Table Structure:

```
yourls_log
----------
click_id
click_time
shorturl
url_id

yourls_url_money
----------------
id
url_id
date
money
```

Comment: Could you please post the table structure?

Comment: I'm not nearly good enough at MySQL to offer advice on how to speed your query up, but what I _can_ do is recommend that you [use an explicit `JOIN` method](http://mysqljoin.com/).

Comment: It is the GROUP BY that is slowing the query because it can't use an index. If there is no specific reason to put it, try removing the GROUP BY. By the way, from your query `DAY` refers to `click_log`.`click_time` and since time could very much vary between entries, I see little reason to group by on `DAY`, no?

Comment: @Abhay I am transforming the date-time to a simple date before doing the GROUP BY.  I do need it, as I am joining a summary table (youls_url_money) with a detail table (yourls_log)

Comment: @Eric, you can try optimizing the GROUP BY by creating an index. As the EXPLAIN shows, the query is using no index for the "click_log" alias. Some indexes you can try with are (`click_time`, `url_id`) and (`click_time`, `shorturl`). It may also make sense if you could modify the WHERE predicates to keep the two "click_time" fields together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but this is much faster (1.5 seconds):

```
SELECT m.date, c.shorturl, m.money, c.clicks, m.money / c.clicks AS CPC
FROM yourls_url_money AS m
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT date( click_time ) AS
DAY , url_id, shorturl, count( click_id ) AS clicks
FROM yourls_log
WHERE click_time >= "2011-07-01"
GROUP BY DAY , url_id, shorturl
) AS c ON m.url_id = c.url_id
AND m.date = c.day
WHERE date >= "2011-07-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created a view under your DBMS and then query the view, the process should complete allot faster. This is mainly due to the fact that a view is data that has already been collected rather than query the data from the offset.

Also look at your server stats, it maybe under too much load?

Comment: Thanks, though the server and mysql are well optimized.  I believe the file-sort is where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date( click_log.click_time ) AS DAY,
   click_log.shorturl AS site,
   daily_dollars.money AS earned,
   count( click_log.click_id ) AS clicks,
   daily_dollars.money / count( click_log.click_id ) AS CPC
FROM `yourls_log` AS click_log, yourls_url_money AS daily_dollars
WHERE click_log.click_time >= "2011-07-01"
AND click_log.url_id = daily_dollars.url_id
AND date( click_log.click_time ) = daily_dollars.date
ORDER BY DAY , click_log.shorturl
```

Comment: Thanks, though this only returns one row... I need a total for each day / site combination.